# How to implement facebook integration in android?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I want to integrate facebook sdk with my app. I have referred the tutorials on devoloper.facebook.com. But I am not able to figure out the logic that I need to do for integrating fb to my existing code. I am tired of trying out things and I really need help.

My app has this login flow.

Activity A-
 1. Login Button
 2. SignUp Button

A-->Login-->Home

A-->SignUp-->Home

The LoginActivity Check whether the user is signed in and if yes, starts the HomeActivity. Otherwise after getting the user credentials launches the HomeActivity.

I want to change it to the following logic.

Activity A-
1. Login Button
2. Connect with Facebook
3. SignUp

**A-->Login-->Home**

**A-->Connect with facebook-->Home(Facebook Session opened).**

**A-->SignUp**

**1.Connect Facebook-->Home(Facebook Session opened)**

**2.Normal SignUp-->Home**

In facebook tutorial page, they are loading different fragments according to the state of the Session. I am new to android and it's really hard for me to implement it to my existing code where I use only activities.
Could anyone provide a sample code or any lead to a probable solution?

Comment: try this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/category/facebook/

Comment: In the above tutorial the implementation is different from the facebook official tutorials. If I use it can I maintain the session through out the app? Because I need facebook connection in different screens.

Comment: yes ofcourse , just you need to store auth token in preferences for futher use

Answer (score 2):

Here you'll find everything you need : https://developers.facebook.com/android/ The tutorial is pretty well written, just follow the steps to get started.

Comment: Please read my question. I asked for other tutorials. My app needs different logic.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. But if you want to use Facebook SDK maybe you should stick to their guidelines.

Moreover, if you're new at Android you should look at Fragments. You said you need Facebook connection in different screens. Fragments can be a good way to achieve this.